# How to tell how much power I can pull from a DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have an old TV with a power supply combined with an inverter for CCFL lamps and I'd like to convert it to use LED backlight with a 12v DC LED driver.
Now, inspecting the board, I've found where to pull 12v from for the external driver, but what I'd like to know beforehand is if the PSU part can handle the extra 3/4 amps@12v and no specs show up on Google if I look up the PSU model, all I've got is a schematic of a similar circuit (how similar? afaik they are all used as PSU + inverter for the same line of TVs) and can identify a few key components that afaik are used in PSUs like the transformer, rectifier, caps for stabilizing the output voltage etc. but still can't conclude anything useful (electronics course in uni starts next semester)

Here's the schematic I found:

1. PCB as it looks like IRL:
   [image: PCB as it looks like IRL]
2. Schematic for the PSU part:
   [image: schematic for the PSU part]
3. Schematic for the inverter part (will probably cut the paths to the PSU part when I'll mount the LED driver):
   [image: schematic for the inverter part]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the 12V supply a switching regulator or an LVR/LDO module?

Comment: No idea, didn't make the circuit

Comment: If it's an LVR then you run the risk of it becoming unstable do to higher load than expected. However, if it's a buck converter it should be alright. You can tell if it's a buck converter by checking for inductors and power FETs.